# Changing date formats in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to find a way to convert a column of dates to a mm/dd/yy format. I initially received data with a date column in milliseconds since epoch format. I used to_datetime to convert it to datetime and now I'm trying to put it into the appropriate format.

I'm thinking my initial step may not have helped.

[Collection of data from TD Ameritrade API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pli7x.png)
[Attempt to transform the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOhE9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's in ms, you need to specify the unit.  In your case:

```
price_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(price_data['datetime'], unit='ms)
```

Here's an example:

```
pd.to_datetime(1577944800000,unit='ms')
```

Output

```
Timestamp('2020-01-02 06:00:00')
```

Comment: This worked well. Thanks. Specifying the unit made the difference.